# merge fields by removing duplicates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update a table by merging the categories separated by comma wherever we have a duplicate IDs for instance:

```
ID            Category
802              A
802              k           
803              x             
804              y
804              z

So here is the desired results that I would like to see after the update is run:
ID            Category
802              A, k
803              x             
804              y, z
```

Thanks

Comment: So? Get to it, matey, time's a-wastin!

Comment: thanks, that post helped me.  thanks again

Comment: Are you indeed *merging* multiple categories into a single one, though, or is it a redesign to store the still multiple categories in a single row as a CSV? The latter would be a shame really.